# Shibboleth SP configuration with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp, identity-provider

our system relies primarily on Cognito for user management, we want to integrate Cognito with third party identity provider which is basically Shibboleth Idp, Cognito requires a metadata file from the Idp , how to get it in case of Shibboleth?.
in Shibboleth docs , it is a requirement to setup and configure Shibboleth SP, It's quite confusing in this case because we have already Cognito working as a service provider ( as it said by aws docs ) . why do we need to setup Shibboleth SP if Cognito will play the role of the service provider?
is it a requirement so that the idp know about all the SPs that he's connecting to ?
in this case , how to setup Cognito with Shibboleth SP ? is it by configuring Cognito as a Relying Party?